# Minecraft NPC not spawning and attacking me on server: null pointer error

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

When I join my server "testing" is printed as expected but the npc is not spawned and does not attack me. Here is the plugin.yml:

```
main: com.megacrafting.MegaParty
version: 1.0
name: Megaparty
depend: [Citizens]
```

Here is the error:

```
[20:58:24 ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerJoinEvent to Megaparty v1.0
org.bukkit.event.EventException: null
        at     org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:306)  ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b78586d-f3356f1]
        at     org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b78586d-f3356f1]
    at   org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:499) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b78586d-f3356f1]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:484) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b78586d-f3356f1]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PlayerList.onPlayerJoin(PlayerList.java:342) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b78586d-f3356f1]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.PlayerList.a(PlayerList.java:162) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b78586d-f3356f1]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.LoginListener.b(LoginListener.java:159) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b78586d-f3356f1]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.LoginListener.e(LoginListener.java:57) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b78586d-f3356f1]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.NetworkManager.a(NetworkManager.java:233) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b78586d-f3356f1]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.ServerConnection.c(ServerConnection.java:140) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b78586d-f3356f1]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:842) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b78586d-f3356f1]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:405) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b78586d-f3356f1]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:678) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b78586d-f3356f1]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:576) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b78586d-f3356f1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.megacrafting.MegaParty.onJoin(MegaParty.java:35) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:302) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-b78586d-f3356f1]
    ... 14 more
```

Here is the code:

```
package com.megacrafting;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import net.citizensnpcs.api.CitizensAPI;
import net.citizensnpcs.api.npc.NPC;
import net.citizensnpcs.api.npc.NPCRegistry;



public class MegaParty extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

private NPCRegistry registry;



public void onEnable() {
    NPCRegistry registry = CitizensAPI.getNPCRegistry();
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);


}

@EventHandler
   public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
    Player p = event.getPlayer();
    p.sendMessage("testing");
    Location loc = p.getLocation();
    NPC npc = registry.createNPC(EntityType.PLAYER, "keys9");
    npc.spawn(loc);

    npc.getNavigator().setTarget(p, true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field `registry` is NULL because you never set it in your `onEnable`.

Change your onEnable to

```
public void onEnable() {
    this.registry = CitizensAPI.getNPCRegistry();
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this); 
}
```